# I am trying to validate my html form when i validate when field it works fine, but validating multiple renders it useless

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bunch of fields
Firstname
LastName
Email
Subject

And want to validate them, validating any of them individually using

```
function validateform(){
var x = document.forms["contactus"]["Firstname"].value

if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("First Name must be Entered");
        return false;
    }
}



var y = document.forms["contactus"] ["LastName"].value;
var i = document.forms["contactus"] ["EmailAddress"].value;
var j = document.forms["contactus"] ["Subject"].value;
```

similiarly doing the same for these won't work if i do them all together but doing one works fine

with this as the html

```
      <form class="contactus" name="contactus" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

any idea why it might not work?

[Javascript Code[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri6gp.png)

[what pops up if its a single var[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlPHt.png)

[the html code for the form head[][3]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7laov.png)

[javascript linking code in the html doc[][4]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7laov.png)

Comment: You don't need to roll your own validation methods, the [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) can do it for you.

Comment: No need to roll your own or use jquery. All modern browsers has already support for this. Just add `required` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#required)) You can also add a `pattern`

Comment: for our assignment we can't use inline styling it has to all be on a seperate document hence the JS and it has to be JS in order to support older browsers

Comment: HI Justine, your screenshots are duplicates (1 and 2 are the same and 3 and 4 are the same). Could you share your full JS?